# Can a failed disk in a RAID array be replaced by a disk with fewer total logical blocks?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, format

Can a failed disk in a RAID array be replaced by a disk with slightly fewer total logical blocks? Specifically, Dell PERC 6 RAID controller; RAID5; Hitachi HUS153014VLS300 with 287140277 blocks; possible replacement Seagate ST3146356SS with 286749488 blocks. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it's Hardware Raid, I would say No.
In general, hardware raid isn't very flexible with disks and normally works best with disks that have the exact same geometry.
Adding a disk that is smaller after a RAID array has been built would most likely cause issues as the RAID array will try to write data past the end of the disk.

If you had created the array with the Seagate disk already in it, then it would probably have worked as it would've accounted for the fact that one of the disks is smaller and thus would not use 100% of the capacity of the bigger disks.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, however I've been told that RAID controllers format to a size slightly smaller than the disk is capable of to account for total block number variation, eg Dell PERCs will format a 36G SCSI disk to 35.8G. I can't find any reference to this on the web, Hence my confusion and question here !!!

Comment: I wouldn't risk it. I'd get a disk the same size.